# ¿Como usar correctamente @change en input file con Vue?

Tags: php, vue.js

Hola tengo un formulario donde tengo 3 input file para subir imágenes, el problema que tengo es que al momento de seleccionar una imagen en un input se sube en los 3, uso la propiedad @change para poder subir mi imagen, bueno este es mi código:

```
<input  type="file"  id="onFileChange" @change="onFileChange"class="form-control">
<input  type="file"  id="onFileChange1"  @change="onFileChange1" class="form-control">
<input  type="file"  id="onFileChange2"  @change="onFileChange2" class="form-control">
```

Dentro de methods:

```
onFileChange(e){
            this.mensajeria.imagen_bien = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(this.mensajeria.imagen_bien);
        },       
         onFileChange1(e){
            this.mensajeria.imagen_deuda = e.target.files[1];
            console.log(this.mensajeria.imagen_deuda);
        },
          onFileChange2(e){
            this.mensajeria.imagen_inasistencia = e.target.files[2];
            console.log(this.mensajeria.imagen_inasistencia);
        },
```

Comment: como seria? e.target.files[0]; para todos?

Comment: Sí, el primer archivo, ya que quieres un solo archivo por input

Comment: El problema que mencionas no se puede [reproducir](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dewdney-65h54?file=/src/App.vue) con el código que proporcionas. Cada propiedad de `mensajeria` recibe el archivo seleccionado en su input correspondiente